# Variable in controller won't update as the variable in the services changes in agularjs

Tags: angularjs

Newbie here!)

I have this **service**:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').service('GroupPageService', function () {
    var group = "";

    this.list = function () {
        return group;
    };

    this.update = function (new_group) {
        group = new_group;
    };
});
```

and this **controller**:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').controller('GroupPageController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, GroupService, $modal, GroupPageService) {

    $scope.groupId = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.group = GroupPageService.list();

    var getGroup = function (id) {
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/enterprises/_groups/"+id
        }).success(function (response) {
            GroupPageService.update(response.group);
        }).error(function () {
            console.log("Error while fetching data of one particular group")
        });
    };

    getGroup($scope.groupId);
}
```

My logic is:

1. getGroup() function fetches data from web API and updates the variable "group" in the service
2. $scope.group is assigned to data that is returned by service.list() function

Data is being returned from the web API correctly but there is a problem with the rest.

**The variable $scope.group is not being updated**

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch for a service method using `$watch`.

```
            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return GroupPageService.list();
            }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                     $scope.group = GroupPageService.list();
                }
            }, true);
```

Comment: A thing worth keeping in mind when you are using watches is that they are evaluated every digest cycle. That being said it's worth considering before you do it if you really need to introduce a watch.

Comment: The only thing that is working for me right now is $watch. Thanks for the answer. But I had to remove the third argument "true", coz it was not working in the initial run

Comment: Cool, But you don't really have to worry about performance here. One primitive comparison by cycle is nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the data that you get back from the API in your success method. The first assignment you do for $scope.group at the top only get executed when the controller runs for the first time. There is nothing updating the contents of $scope.group afterwards.

*Regarding services*: You generally use services when you want to share data across your app. In your case if you want to retrieve those groups once and then inject your service into multiple controllers and have that data available.

Comment: you are  right about services. I have another controller that will use the data from the service. The reason I did $scope.group = GroupPageService.list(); is because, in the second controller I will update the value of the variable "group" in the service and I want the $scope.group in the first controller to be instantly updated too. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: A possible solution for that could be raising an event that the data has changed. I recommend taking a look at the following tutorial for that: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you assign a new value in your service you are changing the reference to that value. What you should do for your code to work is transform your group variable into an object:

```
app.service('GroupPageService', function () {
    var group = {name: "xxx"} ;

    this.list = function () {
          return group;
      };

    this.update = function (new_group) {
          group.name = new_group;
    };
});
```